# xslt: time ago test

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xpath

using xslt how do i test if a date was within the last (say) 15 days?

input:

- date in format dd/mm/yy
- X number of days

output:

- if the date occured within X days of now

eg recent('02/07/10',30) would return true iff 02/07/10 was 30 days in the past

some steps i got:

main func

```
    <xsl:function name="custom:monthtodays">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="daysago"/>
    <xsl:variable name="daycountnow" select="year-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())*365+day-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())+custom:monthtodays(month-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())" />
    <xsl:variable name="datedaycount" select="numeric(substring($date,1,2))+numeric(substring($date,7,2))*365+custom:monthtodays(numeric(substring($date,4,2)))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$daycountnow - $datedaycount - $daysago > 0"/>
</xsl:function>
```

helper func

```
 <xsl:function name="custom:monthtodays">
    <xsl:param name="month"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$month =1"> <xsl:value-of select="0"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =2"> <xsl:value-of select="31"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =3"> <xsl:value-of select="59"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =4"> <xsl:value-of select="90"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =5"> <xsl:value-of select="120"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =6"> <xsl:value-of select="151"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =7"> <xsl:value-of select="181"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =8"> <xsl:value-of select="212"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =9"> <xsl:value-of select="243"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =10"> <xsl:value-of select="273"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =11"> <xsl:value-of select="304"/> </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$month =12"> <xsl:value-of select="334"/> </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:function>
```

but this doesnt take account of leap years and the like ... surely there is a betterway?

Comment: xls is the extension for Excel Spreadsheets.  I think you mean XSLT, and you should edit your post and tags to correct this.

Comment: Also, you should post some sample input and expected output, along with the XSL code you've tried.  SO is not a place where people do your (home)work for you.

Comment: a naive attempt has been added... good spot on xls vs xsl.

Comment: XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0 has not been made for such a kind of data processing. It is very poor at handling dates and math. However, most XSLT engines support extension functions which makes date handling very easy. Which engine are you using?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: at the moment i'm using .Net 4.0 (under C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it in XSLT 1.0. As you are using .Net 4.0, you should be available to use the microsoft extension function, and write your own (javascript) function to do the date difference.

Here is the transformation. Note the JavaScript function is quite crude, and assumes the date is in DD/MM/YY format:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace"> 

<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user"> 
function datecheck(dateString)  
{ 
    // Get today's date
    var today = new Date();

    // Clear down any time portion
    today.setHours(0);
    today.setMinutes(0);
    today.setSeconds(0);
    today.setMilliseconds(0);

    // Length of day in milliseconds
    var one_day = 1000*60*60*24;

    // Convert date string into a date
    var day = parseInt(dateString.substring(0, 2), 10);
    var month = parseInt(dateString.substr(3, 2), 10);
    var year = 2000 + parseInt(dateString.substr(6, 2), 10);
    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

    // Get date difference
    var diff = Math.ceil((today.getTime()-date.getTime()) / one_day);
    return (diff &lt;= 30);
} 
</msxsl:script> 

<xsl:template match="/*"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="user:datecheck(string(.))"/> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply it on this input (assuming today is 23/07/2010)

```
<date>02/07/10</date>
```

You should get the return value of **true**

When you apply it on this input

```
<date>02/06/10</date>
```

You should get the return value of **false**

Comment: Excellent this works (after modifications) nicely, though its a shame that .net doesnt support xlst 2.0! 

Modifications to get it to work - in C# allow scripts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163499.aspx

On code - wrap everything within msxsl:script with <![CDATA[ ]]> also replace the &lt; with <

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="my:isWithinDays(/*, 30)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:isWithinDays" as="xs:boolean">
   <xsl:param name="pDate" as="xs:string"/>
   <xsl:param name="pDaysDuration" as="xs:integer"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vvalidDate" select=
     "concat('20',
             substring($pDate,7),
             '-',
             substring($pDate,4,2),
             '-',
             substring($pDate,1,2))"/>

     <xsl:sequence select=
      "current-date() - xs:date($vvalidDate) 
      le 
       xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('P',$pDaysDuration, 'D'))"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>02/07/10</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
true
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>20/06/10</t>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
false
```

**Note**: this transformation was performed today, 21/07/10.

Comment: Pants .Net 4.0 doesnt seem to implement XSLT 2.0 :*( any way of getting this to work in v1.0?

Comment: @GreyCloud: Then you can only use extension functions. If you used an XSLT 1.0 processor that implements EXSLT (such as Saxon 6.x), you could have a look at the XSLT datetime module.